# How to determine if a dataframe column contains a particular list, independently of its order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Col1'] = [['B'],['A','D','B'],['D','C']]
df['Col2'] = [1,2,4]
df

      Col1  Col2
0      [B]   1
1  [A,D,B]   2
2    [D,C]   4
```

I would like to know if Col1 contains the list [B,A,D], without caring for the order of the lists (those inside the column as the one to check).
I would like therefore to get here a True answer.

How could I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are not duplicated you can compare `set`s:

```
L = ['B','A','D']
print (df['Col1'].map(set).eq(set(L)))
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

If want scalar output- `True` or `False` test if at least one `True` in column by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
print (df['Col1'].map(set).eq(set(['B','A','D'])).any())
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
l=['B','A','D']
[set(i)==set(l) for i in df['Col1']]
#[False, True, False]
```

Comment: Thank your for this great answer. How could I get just a True value from your proposal ? I need to compare this with a boolean value. Sorry if it's basic, I am quite new with python !

Comment: @Ewdlam do you mean : `df[[set(i)==set(l) for i in df['Col1']]]` ?

Comment: It was not what I meant but it is very helpfull for what I'm doing, thanks a lot ! jezrael gave me the answer

Answer (score 2):

IIUC method of `get_dummies`

```
l=['B','A','D']
df.Col1.str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')[l].all(1)
Out[197]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```